# PHP Mockery partial test double not calling method from parent class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery

I'm confused why my partial test double is not calling a method correctly. These are my classes:

```php
abstract class Model
{
    public function update(array $attributes) {
        $this->performUpdate($attributes);
    }

    abstract protected function performUpdate(array $attributes);
}

class Product extends Model
{
    protected function performUpdate(array $attributes)
    {
        print_r($attributes);
    }
}

$mock = Mockery::mock(Product::class)->makePartial();

$mock->update([]); // the 'performUpdate' method never gets called
```

When the code is run, `performUpdate` in the `Product` class is never called. The 'update' method is called as expected, but the real `performUpdate` method is never called. Instead, it just returns null as if it were not a partial mock. Partial mocks are supposed to defer to the method in the mocked class if no expectation is set up, so why isn't my method getting called?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods` when creating the mock. This will resolve the issue of you not seeing the output.

Comment: That’s not true. The method is not called. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works fine. Since you don't return anything from the function `performUpdate` you're getting `null` back. If you try the same thing in the console you'll see the text

Comment: But I’m not taking about returning anything. Running that code should print an empty array. For me it doesn’t. It does for you? I’ll have to check again.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was testing with a class where the method was public. I've edited the answer to show how to use it with protected methods.

Comment: But I’m not mocking the protected method. The protected method is an internal call. Since it’s a partial mock, the call to the public update method should call performUpdate internally as normal, but it’s not.

Comment: Yes I know, but internally when mockery tries to call the method it checks if it's protected, as it doesn't just forward the call to the original class. If you enable mocking protected methods, you'll be able to call them on partial mocks too. I tested it and it worked correctly.

Comment: But what is special about this case? Any other time I create a partial mock I don't need to add the `shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods` flag. It just forward calls to the mocked class as expected. It must have something to do with the fact that the protected `performUpdate` method is implemented in the child class rather than on the same level that `update` is defined.

Comment: Gathering what I saw while experimenting it only has to do with it being protected, not the fact it comes from an inherited class or anything of that sort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189525/discussion-between-borisu-and-flyingl123).